# Youtube-dl Python saving mp4 file

Tags: python, youtube-api, web-crawler

I am using the Youtube-DL library and I noticed that when I am scraping videos some .mp4 files do not get saved, but yet the other files do.

Here is my code

```
     ydl_opts = {
    "download_archive": "./data/en-downloaded.txt",
    "restrictfilenames": True,
    "nooverwrites": True,
    "socket_timeout": 1,
    "youtube_include_dash_manifest": True,
    "writeinfojson": True,
    "writesubtitles": True,
    "format": "bestaudio/best",
    # "allsubtitles": True,
    "subtitlesformat": "ttml",
    "progress_hooks": [my_hook],
    "subtitlelangs": lang,
    "writeautosub": True,
    "keepvideo:": True,
    # "--write-srt": True,
    "postprocessors": [{"key": "FFmpegExtractAudio",  "preferredcodec": "wav", "preferredquality": "192",}],
    "prefer_ffmpeg": True,
    "format": "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio",
    "outtmpl": "data/raw_files/%(title)s.%(ext)s",
}
```

Where do I actually tell youtube-dl to make sure you save the .mp4 file?

Comment: Can you provide a YouTube URL that fialed, please?

Comment: `format` is used twice with different parameters.

Comment: with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        term = 'apple'

         ydl.download([f"https://www.youtube.com/results?sp=EgQIBCgB&q={term}"]) @FrancescoMantovani

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks. This problem is so hard!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your keepvideo option with an extra colon inside the quotation marks,
replace

```
"keepvideo:": True,
```

with

```
"keepvideo": True,
```

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl defaults to best streams unless something different is specified.

Comment: How do I save the .mp4 file in python like how I have it?